# android studio specifically R.id.editText

Tags: java, android, xml

Hello this is my first time creating a beginners application with android studio and i have been following step by step to create the tutorial message app but i have run into a problem which I'm hoping someone could clarify what i am missing or what I'm doing wrong but when calling the findViewById(R.Id.editText); portion of the code to show the edit text section on the second activity it cannot find the referenced symbol and i cannot add the reference by pushing alt+enter as it does not show an option to import and i have no idea what a resource value is or creating a Field for it does.

This is the MainActivity.java file

```js
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    /** Called when the user taps the Send button */
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

This is the activity_main.XML file

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="28dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="@string/edit_message"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
            android:onClick="sendMessage"
            android:text="@string/button_send"
            app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my DisplayMessageActivity.java File

```js
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class DisplayMessageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

        // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
        TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText(message);
    }
}
```

This is my activity_display_message.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my Strings.xml

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">My First App</string>
    <string name="edit_message">Enter a message</string>
    <string name="button_send">Send</string>
</resources>
```

If someone can point out where it is the EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText); part is going wrong i would greatly appreciate it.
Thanks :)

Comment: Which layout contains Edittext. None of the above mentioned layout has edittext

Comment: `EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);` is absent in xml

Comment: You should have edit text in main activity.xml

Comment: Try my answer..

Answer (score 0):

In **MainActivity** write this :

Replace :

```
TextView editText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Instad of :

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

In **DisplayMessageActivity** write this :

Replace:

```
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
```

Instead of :

```
TextView textView =  findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Comment: If it solves your problem then mark it as correct for future visitors

Comment: @Meep If you want to edit that text then take edittext in xml. and find reference of what you have in xml only.

Answer (score 0):

Replace activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:hint="@string/edit_message"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: sorry i had deleted android:id="@+id/editText"; as i entered it to see if it would work but it didnt and i tried replacing the EditText line with the line you gave me but it didnt work as the editText); still shows up red and stops the app from displaying the next activity

Answer (score 0):

You have not created EditText anywhere in your code and hence the program can’t find the id for the edit text you are asking it by calling **(R.id.editText)**.

So first create an EditText in your mainActivity and give that id -

**android:id="@+id/editText”**

Now you can write code and use

**EditText ed=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);**

Then you can use

**ed.getText();**

and print whatever message you want to display in new activity.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you miss place the id at `textview` in your code,  in your xml  the id is `textview2`

```
<TextView
      android:id="@+id/textView2"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
      android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
      android:text="TextView"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

But in your code you find view by is id

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textView);
```

Simply use code bellow

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

// Capture the layout's TextView and set the string as its text
TextView textView2 = findViewById(R.id.textView2);
textView2.setText(message);
```